# Can I search question by user reputation?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, reputation, users, search

Is there some way to search questions of users with low reputation or with high reputation?

Comment: Nope. Curious; why would you want to? Also, you can search by *post score*.

Comment: @AndrewBarber At first I had the same reaction you did. Questions/Answers should be judged on their content, not the user posting them. BUT, with questions specifically... high rep users tend to ask more interesting/novel questions since they have been here longer, know how to search, and aren't just looking for a one-off.

Comment: @Gray Hmmm.... that is a good point. And who wouldn't want to answer a question by [Jon, Darin, BalusC, Marc, Hans, Vonc, SLaks, etc?](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Because: http://xkcd.com/356/

Comment: I found the answer! http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/162190/unanswered-questions-from-users-with-reputation-100. This one in particular is for >= 100, but it should be easy to modify to suite your tastes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are comfortable with SQL, all the data you need to find questions by the asker's reputation are available on [Data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) ([FAQ](https://data.stackexchange.com/help)). You'll have to write your own queries, unless you're lucky and someone beat you to it.

That said, as everyone else has mentioned, there's little point to what you're trying to do. Your focus should be on the content, not the user(s).

Comment: I *always* forget that option.

Comment: Here something similar http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/145349/unasweredjquerypostsfromuserswithlowreputation

Comment: http://xkcd.com/356/

Comment: Perhaps [a list of questions asked by higher rep users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1164063/get-valuable-unanswered-python-questions) may be of use.

Answer (score 7):

No there is no way to do it.

> But questions are not related to user reputation, each question has its own vote showing its popularity. [You can search and sort question by votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes)

Answer (score 3):

There is a way, kind-of.

1. Find a high reputation user. This can be done by hitting the user page.
2. When you look on the user page of [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), the search bar includes the user id. Do a search on that user, and you can search just what that particular high reputation user has asked.

Comment: I guess that's the next-best thing. Clunky, but I personally think the idea of searching for content based on the user is weird to begin with ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber it might be helpful for finding answers to questions you have if they are strong on a subject you have questions on or in finding questions you can answer if they need help in a subject you are strong on.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Searching by user isn't weird IMO. Often I remember who posted a certain answer I want to find. Searching by user rep is weird though.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Oops... that's actually what I meant to type!

Comment: I want to find the questions of **all** users with low reputation...